# ggplot boxplot but with boxes extending to 5th and 95th percentiles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have a boxplot summarize the distribution of some underlying data, but in place of the whiskers extending to the 5th and 95th, I would like the boxes to extend to the 5th and 95th.

Standard boxplot with outliers and whiskers removed:

```
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, coef = 0)
```

[image]
Boxplot with whiskers at 5th and 95th:

```
p + stat_summary(geom = "boxplot", 
                 fun.data = function(x) setNames(quantile(x, c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95)), 
                                                 c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")))
```

[image]

But what I really want is the boxes (no whiskers) to extend to the 5th and 95th, so a combination of both of these modifications. Is there a way to specify the box-generating function in `stat_summary()`?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a slightly "hacky" method of doing it, but the easiest way might be to just use `geom_segment` for each cylinder class. This will allow you to specify the width of the boxplot and the values that you want the boxplot to reach. But you could then play around with `aes()` and also add in a median line using `stat_summary()` if desired.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_segment(aes(x = 4, xend = 4, y = quantile(subset(mtcars, mtcars$cyl==4)$mpg,0.95), yend = quantile(subset(mtcars, mtcars$cyl==4)$mpg, 0.05)), color = 'firebrick1', lwd = 28)
```

Comment: Thanks @colonelforbin97, I hadn't thought of `geom_segment`. It could work, although it would take more to get the mean/median lines (as you mention) and I also want to fill/color by groups, with the outline line to match a grouped histogram (lots actually going on, sorry, should have specified I wanted other 'features' of the boxplot). Will wait to accept this one, hoping there is a more direct route, but this is creative and I'll accept if nothing else comes around!

Comment: Sounds good @BryanMichael. This is definitely a 'shortcut' way of getting something along the lines of a boxplot, but is ultimately inefficient and would be difficult to integrate with other features and plots. Let us know what you come up with. Thanks!